# Make GitHub's bug tracker read-only

Tags: github

Is there the ability to make GitHub's bug tracker read-only? I've setup an organization with a public repository. I want only certain people to be able to create new bugs but still want it to be read-only to the public. This is a requirement for an assignment in software-engineering class. I'm supposed to make it write-accessible by another project group but read-only for the TAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public repository on GitHub.com will allow anyone to create an Issue.  (I'm assuming by bug-tracker you are referring to [GitHub Issues](https://help.github.com/articles/about-issues/).

To resolve your issue, I suggest [disabling issues](https://help.github.com/articles/disabling-issues/) on your public repository and using a private repository for the explicit purpose of tracking bugs. This will narrow the scope of people who can enter a bug to people with access to the private repository.

If sharing the contents of the bug-tracking list on the public repository is a concern, you can create a small script to accomplish this. You would setup the [issues event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuesevent) webhook to fire whenever a bug is entered as an issue in your private repository. Your script could parse the payload to confirm that an issue was opened (versus closed, assigned, etc.), and then use the API to [update a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file) in the public repository that lists the bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough. I had an idea that I couldn't make this work solely using Github.